# Flutter - Audio Player

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

hello i am new to flutter

i am trying to play audio files from url or network but which to use because

i searched google it showed many but which one to use.

if possible can show an example on how to create like below image

i want to create an audio player like this [image]

kindly help...

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 6):

An answer that shows how to do everything in your screenshot would probably not fit in a StackOverflow answer (audio code, UI code, and how to extract audio wave data) but I will give you some hopefully useful pointers.

Using the [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) plugin you can load audio from these kinds of URLs:

- `https://example.com/track.mp3` (any web URL)
- `file:///path/to/file.mp3` (any file URL with permissions)
- `asset:///path/to/asset.mp3` (any Flutter asset)

You will probably want a playlist, and here is how to define one:

```dart
final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
  AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track1.mp3')),
  AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track2.mp3')),
  AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track3.mp3')),
  AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track4.mp3')),
  AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track5.mp3')),
]);
```

Now to play that, you create a player:

```dart
final player = AudioPlayer();
```

Set the playlist:

```dart
await player.setAudioSource(playlist);
```

And then as the user clicks on things, you can perform these operations:

```dart
player.play();
player.pause();
player.seekToNext();
player.seekToPrevious();
player.seek(Duration(milliseconds: 48512), index: 3);
player.dispose(); // to release resources once finished
```

For the screen layout, note that just_audio includes an example which looks like this, and since there are many similarities to your own proposed layout, you may get some ideas by looking at [its code](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio/example):

[image]

Finally, for the audio wave display, you can use [just_waveform](https://pub.dev/packages/just_waveform) to extract waveform data out of an audio file. That package includes an example demonstrating how this waveform data can be rendered. Since it takes time to extract the waveform data from an audio file, in many cases it is also possible to "fake" the audio waveform if it's not terribly important that the waveform represent the true audio. On the rendering side, another option besides following the implementation guide in the just_waveform example is to use an additional package called [audio_wave](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_wave) to render waveform data that you give it.

Comment: i am getting error when i am adding just_audio package in pubspec. Because jain_books depends on just_audio >=0.7.0-nullsafety.3 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-259.9.beta <3.0.0, version solving failed.

Comment: Either upgrade to the latest Flutter SDK (i.e. `flutter upgrade`) or downgrade just_audio to an earlier version (i.e. `0.6.15+1`).

Comment: Thanks for helping!! any chance you know how to play audio from list like shown in first figure??

Comment: Isn't that what I explained in my answer? I guess I didn't do a good job of it :-) When I said "playlist" I was talking about a list, that's the same thing as what you're asking. The example I pointed to you demonstrates that - the example is complete so you can run it and see.

Comment: i didnt understand can you help how to implement or provide me a similar code for that. @RyanHeise

Comment: I pointed you to a complete example that you can download and run. Can you tell me specifically what you think it's missing? Doesn't it demonstrate exactly how to play from a playlist?

Comment: no it demonstrates only player that is being played i want to play from list and when clicked on the list data it should take me to the player and play the audio

Comment: Your question is probably too broad, and as I hinted, a complete answer to your question would not fit in a StackOverflow answer. Your first question is choosing an audio plugin that supports your playlist requirements, and the second question is how to achieve the layout, and then a third question is how to achieve the navigation between two screens. I have focused on the first question, and recommend you create separate questions for each specific layout or navigation question you have, the more specific the better.

Comment: you can share the code trough github abd sorry for not being so specific next time i will put that in mind so can help?

Comment: If you want someone to write you a working app according to your screenshots and upload it to GitHub, I think you have the wrong website. Maybe you can try freelancer.com or upwork.com. StackOverflow is for asking narrow/specific questions. I'm sorry I will not be able to help you with an ask of that scope.